# How to tell when 2 variables with same value will have different identities?

Tags: python, memory

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> print id(x),id(y)
43259384 43258744

>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
>>> print id(x),id(y)
5417464 5417464
```

As you can see the IDs are different for the first print but the same for the second print. Why? What determines whether or not the IDs of 2 variables will be the same after they have been assigned the same value?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This question regards lists, which should not have the same `id`. The whole content of this question is not explained by the link

Comment: Numbers are immutable. Because of this, Python implementations *may* utilize Interning (as described in the answers in the Related post) - Java does the same thing for a limited set of Integers. Other language implementations (i.e. ELisp and MRI Ruby) use "immediate values" as another optimization which has the same result when comparing identities.

Comment: @jamylak the lists do not have the same id.

Comment: @user2246674 just post that as an answer instead of comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The small integers are getting **interned**.

> Short ints with small values (typically between -1 and 99
>         inclusive) are "interned" -- whenever a result has such a value,
>         an existing short int with the same value is returned.  This is
>         **not done** for long ints with the same values.

Further,

> But code may exist that uses 'is' for comparisons of short ints and
>         happens to work because of this interning.  Such code may fail
>         if used with long ints.)

However, this **isn't** behavior that should be relied upon as it is **implementation-specific**. It isn't going to work for larger integers and interning isn't guaranteed, so you shouldn't be using `is` here.
Other than integers, strings may also be interned.

([PEP-0237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/))

Comment: On CPython the range is -5 to 256.

Answer (score 0):

As @jamylak points out, your first test compares the `id` of two lists, not the integers they contain.  If you actually compare the integers in the lists -- for example `print id(x[0]), id(y[0])` -- you may get the same `id`.

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print id(x[0]), id(y[0])
4298179016 4298179016
```

Comment: This is true due to interning as shown in the link by @Ignacio  but I was more so emphasizing the fact that list are mutable.